# Getting 403 while accessing https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/

Tags: linkedin-api

Equinix uses http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/ for getting information about any company and we publish this info in our Equinix Marketplace website for that Company's storefront.

We are using Spring Social Network API to connect to LinkedIn API.  It was working before and it started giving below error now:

> ###[WARN] 2015-07-02 00:17:17:839 [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] - GET request for "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/universal-name=tata-communication:(id,name,universal-name,email-domains,company-type,ticker,website-url,industry,status,logo-url,square-logo-url,blog-rss-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,description,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers)?" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler ###[ERROR] 2015-07-02 00:17:18:037 [com.equinix.gse.gsd.servlet.SocialNetworkFlowHandlerServlet] - SocialNetworkServiceException

Is there anyway to get any company information via API for any user?

Comment: have you find the solution for 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `Companies API` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

As per LinkedIn,

> All calls to Companies API endpoints will require the authenticated
>   user to be flagged as an administrator of the LinkedIn Company Page
>   that is the target of the API call.  You become the administrator of a
>   page when you create it.  If the page already exists, you will have to
>   contact the existing administrator to grant admin access to other
>   LinkedIn members.
>
> Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the
>   appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company.

So from now onwards, you will have to become an administrator for that company page to access the `Companies API`.

(This [LinkedIn page](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17481/ft/eng) might be helpful to know more about getting the appropriate admin permissions.)

Comment: Is there anyway to get any company information via linkedin API for any user? For example a super admin role?

Comment: For each company page, you would have to get admin permissions to access the Company API.